# Problems when compiling the Open Kinect drivers for Python on Windows

Tags: python, kinect

I'm trying to compile [the Open Kinect drivers for Python on Windows](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started#Windows) [I made a Make file with CMake (link)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qsz0y.png) and tried compiling it with VC++ Express.

Everything seems to compile alright (the viewer sample works), except for the Python wrapper. I changed the output folder of freenect, which places freenect.lib in another folder to prevent a collision. When I changed this it and try to compile cython_freenect I get:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ZERO_CHECK, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>------ Build started: Project: freenect, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
2>     Creating library C:/IvoPython/Kinect/Driver/lib/Release/freenect.lib and object C:/IvoPython/Kinect/Driver/lib/Release/freenect.exp
2>  freenect.vcxproj -> C:\IvoPython\Kinect\Driver\Release\freenect.dll
3>------ Build started: Project: freenect_sync, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
3>     Creating library C:/IvoPython/Kinect/Driver/lib/Release/freenect_sync.lib and object C:/IvoPython/Kinect/Driver/lib/Release/freenect_sync.exp
3>  freenect_sync.vcxproj -> C:\IvoPython\Kinect\Driver\Release\freenect_sync.dll
4>------ Build started: Project: cython_freenect, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
4>LINK : fatal error LNK1149: output filename matches input filename 'C:\IvoPython\Kinect\Driver\lib\Release\freenect.lib'
========== Build: 3 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

It's strange that it can't find the library, because it just created it and I manually linked it to the library.

[image]

**Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?** As far as I know I followed all the steps in the [Python Wrapper for Windows guide](http://openkinect.org/wiki/Python_Wrapper_Windows).

Comment: Please note that I have absolutely zero previous experience with compiling things, so if I'm missing something obvious, please enlighten me ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow the linker got a wrong argument: the output file matches one of the input files.
Is C:/IvoPython/Kinnect/Driver an exisiting path from your download ?

You should try to choose a build  target outside Kinnect, maybe C:/IvoPython/build

Comment: I had to manually set it a folder in CMAKE: http://i.stack.imgur.com/qsz0y.png All files but cython_freenect build properly. I think the problem is partly due to cython_freenect building its dependencies, even if they already exist. I'll try to put it somewhere completely different though

Comment: It seems this is similar to an earlier fixed problem, though I didn't start with trying to compile after it was fixed. https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect/issues/235

Comment: It turns out I had moved them out and added a link to their new location, however I forgot to remove the old link. So it said it couldn't find them. The build now completely successfully :D